# populate a Jlist From another Jlist using a single button

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

Hi there I need urgent help on populating the second Jlist, I have successfully populated the first from a DB but an having huge difficulty in finding a way to populate the second.

I would like to,

get selected from Jlist1,
click button,
add selected to Jlist2

My code, add the selected to Jlist2 but when I select a new value from Jlist1 and click the button it replaces the existing value in Jlist2 which I don't want. I want it to add to the list not write over it.

```
private void butCounter1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String selec =(String) LCandidate.getSelectedValue();
        DefaultListModel def = new DefaultListModel();
        def.addElement(selec);

        Lmyvotes.setModel(def);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second list only adds one element every time and replaces it with the previous element because you created `DefaultListModel` inside `actionPerforemed` method.

To solve this issuse, define it as an instance.

```
private DefaultListModel modelOne = new DefaultListModel();//if you need it
private DefaultListModel modelTwo = new DefaultListModel();

//inside the constructor
//...
LCandidate.setModel(modelOne);
Lmyvotes.setModel(modelTwo);
//.....

//Inside actionPerformed

private void butCounter1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String selec =(String) LCandidate.getSelectedValue();
      //  DefaultListModel def = new DefaultListModel();  << don't need this line 
        def.addElement(selec);

      //  Lmyvotes.setModel(def); << don't need this line too
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much cant believe I struggle so much on something so easy

Comment: @user2672140: you're welcome, I always have the same problem ;)